# Null Pointer When StartActivity on Grid Layout Adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, grid-layout, onclicklistener

I have a button inside grid layout adapter, and I want to set OnClickListener in getView method to start activity,
But I have Null Pointer Exception when I click it..
This is my code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

            LoaderImageView thumnail=new LoaderImageView(mCon, "");
            LinearLayout thum=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumn);
            thumnail.setImageDrawable(mList.get(position).getPict());
            thum.addView(thumnail);

            TextView namaPro=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.namaPro);
            namaPro.setText(mList.get(position).getNama());

            /*Rate* Menyusul*/

            Button view=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewlist);
            view.setId(position);
            view.setOnClickListener(new onClick());

            return convertView;
    }

    class onClick extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(mCon, DetailProduct.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
```

Anything wrong with my code above??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onclicklistener try calling startActivity() with the Context instance. The adapter will not have a context by itself. So you have to specify the context for starting the activity.

```
 class onClick extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(mCon, DetailProduct.class);
        mCon.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Solved,,,Thank u bro,,but it need to addFlag on intent,,addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),, :)